# Cron Job ssh every week

Tags: linux, cron

I want to cron sh script via ssh, when i do crontab -e from my terminal it displays :

```
1 0 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate (ipadress) > /dev/null
```

someone can tell me what this line means for? should i replace it with :

```
0 0 * * * mypath/tofile.sh ?
```

Comment: That depends on what you want the job to do. Should it run on the local machine and do something remote, or are you completely on the remote machine?

Comment: I want to save it only on remote machine

Comment: my question is : when i use crontab -e to cron a job it shows me : 1 0 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate (ipadress) > /dev/null what should i do after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you do *not* want to replace the line in the existing crontab - it is there to sync the system time.

Instead you want to add your cron entry on the next line. Your resultant file should look like this:

```
1 0 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate (ipadress) > /dev/null
0 0 * * * mypath/tofile.sh ?
```

This will run the script `mypath.tofile.sh` on the *remote* machine, i.e. the script must be installed on the remote machine. It will execute daily at midnight. If you want it to run only once per week, say on Monday at 00:00, try this:

```
0 0 * * 1 mypath/tofile.sh ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i'll try it and go back here to post results.

Comment: Hello, i successfully setup the cron job, thanks for your advice.